# Pipes flooding downstairs

Tags: plumbing

While my daughter was showering upstairs, one of my downstairs toilets started flooding with hot water coming from underneath the toilets. It flooded my bathroom n living room. Then in the master bathroom someone flushed the toilet and it flooded over and I notice that in the shower it had water coming up from the drain. What could the problem be?

Comment: Do you have a septic system, or city sewer?

Answer (score 2):

The drain line is plugged beyond the downstairs toilet.

Comment: Hi, Dan. We usually ask for more than a single sentence, accurate though it may be. Would you mind filling this out a bit, perhaps with your reasoning?

Comment: He's right. The drain line is blocked.

Comment: To say anything more would be to explain how to clear a drain for which we already have better answers. I think it best to close this as a duplicate of the preferred "how to clear a drain" question. But I like to give even a duplicate an answer they can use.